# Ruby double pipe usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file which have different paths for remote server and local server.

```
Remote server path:
"/app/public/front-end/public/JSONModels/IdPairing/Text.json"
Local server path:
"public/front-end/public/JSONModels/IdPairing/Text.json"
```

I basically wanna make sure my app finds correct path for the file regardless of which server I'm at.

So I found something like double pipe ( || ) in Ruby syntax like below:

```
File.read("/app/public/front-end/public/JSONModels/IdPairing/Text.json" || "public/front-end/public/JSONModels/IdPairing/Text.json")
```

But it seems like it only reads the first path. How do you make sure it reads the second path if the file is not being found in the first path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why it doesn't work for you:

```
irb(main):001:0> File.read("some made up name")
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - some made up name
        from (irb):1:in `read'
        from (irb):1
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> File.read("some made up name" || "Gemfile")
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - some made up name
        from (irb):2:in `read'
        from (irb):2
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

As you can see, when you try to read a file that doesn't exist, Ruby explodes.

That's what [exist?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-exist-3F) is for.

## What you should do

```
irb(main):003:0> filename = File.exist?("some made up name") ? "some made up name" : "Gemfile"
=> "Gemfile"
irb(main):004:0> File.read(filename)
```

That's one way to do it, at least.

Comment: To properly indent multiple lines of code, indent them by four spaces or press the "`{}`" button in the formatting toolbar which will do it for you.

Comment: I just did as what you said and your syntax works in rails console but when I actually run the app in development environment, it gives me an error saying the syntax is wrong. Does this syntax not work in Rails app?

Comment: Should work. Do you want to update your original q with your current code?

Answer (score 1):

A lazy way is:

```
begin
  File.read("/app/public/front-end/public/JSONModels/IdPairing/Text.json")
rescue
  File.read("public/front-end/public/JSONModels/IdPairing/Text.json")
end
```

Comment: this uses exceptions for flow control :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put those paths into an environment specific config file. Take a look at [railsconfig/config](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) on GitHub.

After you have installed the gem, you can add a configuration to `config/settings/<RAILS_ENV>.yml` like

```
json_file: /app/public/front-end/public/JSONModels/IdPairing/Text.json
```

where `<RAILS_ENV>` can be `development`, `test`, `production` or a custom environment.

And in your code, just

```
File.read(Settings.json_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try these in sequence, define a list first:

```
FILES = [
  "/app/public/front-end/public/JSONModels/IdPairing/Text.json",
  "public/front-end/public/JSONModels/IdPairing/Text.json"
]
```

Then you can simply open the first one that exists:

```
path = FILES.find { |f| File.exists?(f) }

File.open(path)
```

The problem was that `"string" || "string"` will never work, the first string is logically true and the rest is irrelevant and ignored.